# Различное отображение шрифтов в браузерах

Tags: html, css, wordpress, браузер, веб-дизайн

Привет,у меня есть сайт на WordPress но когда я запускаю его в различных браузерах то шрифты отображаются немножко по разному. К примеру в MicrosoftEdge все края очень гладкие и красивые(как нужно),а вот в опере и хроме с квадратика меленькими на краях.
Можете подкинуть решение данной проблемы и поподробней обяснить(я знаю что браузеры по разному рендерят шрифты).

Comment: Что за шрифт,как подключен?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" id="font-style-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A400%2C400i%2C600%2C700%2C700i%2C800&amp;subset=cyrillic&amp;ver=4.7.8" type="text/css" media="all">

Вот так подключил.Называется OpenSans

Comment: "я знаю что браузеры по разному рендерят шрифты" ... тогда не ясно в чем вопрос заключается ... используйте шрифты оптимизированные под web, если конвертировали под разные браузеры сами, попробуйте конвертировать чем-то другим ... да пожалуй и все ...

Comment: Мне нужно скачать шрифт с гугл и сконвертировать его в разные типы?Можете написать где их лучше конвертировать?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth